# perl Schwartzian Transform?

Tags: perl, sorting, transform

i had script:

```
# N1089767N_7_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78919186.xml
# N1089767N_7_SWOPT_25-Jun-2011_72745892.xml
# N1089772L_9_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78979055.xml
# N1089772L_9_SWOPT_20-Jul-2011_69380887.xml
# N1089772L_9_SWOPT_29-Jun-2011_74754662.xml
open( CONSULTS, "confile" );
@scons = <CONSULTS>;
close CONSULTS;
my %is_trade_id_unique;
foreach ( reverse sort consort @scons ) {
    chomp;

    #print $_. "\n";
    if ( $_ =~ m/(\w+_\d+_\w+)_(\d+)-([A-Za-z]{3})-2011_(\d+)[.]xml/i ) {
        my ( $trade_id, $date, $month, $row_num ) = ( $1, $2, $3, $4 );
        if ( !$is_trade_id_unique{$trade_id} ) {
            print $_. "\n";
            $is_trade_id_unique{$trade_id} = 1;
        }

        #print $_."\n";
    }

}

#N1089767N_7_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78919186.xml
sub consort {
    $aa = $a;
    $bb = $b;

  # save our variables because our sort routine affects them.  If I "chomp $a"
  # that will actually change the line seen in the foreach loop that calls this.

    chomp $aa;
    chomp $bb;

    $aa =~ s/^  *//;
    $bb =~ s/^  *//;

    my %months = (
        FY  => 0,
        Jan => 1,
        Feb => 2,
        Mar => 3,
        Apr => 4,
        May => 5,
        Jun => 6,
        Jul => 7,
        Aug => 8,
        Sep => 9,
        Oct => 10,
        Nov => 11,
        Dec => 12,
    );

    my ( $trade_id,  $date,  $month,  $row_num );
    my ( $btrade_id, $bdate, $bmonth, $brow_num );
    if ( $aa =~ m/(\w+_\d+_\w+)_(\d+)-([A-Za-z]{3})-2011_(\d+)[.]xml/i ) {
        ( $trade_id, $date, $month, $row_num ) = ( $1, $2, $months{$3}, $4 );
    }
    if ( $bb =~ m/(\w+_\d+_\w+)_(\d+)-([A-Za-z]{3})-2011_(\d+)[.]xml/i ) {
        ( $btrade_id, $bdate, $bmonth, $brow_num ) =
          ( $1, $2, $months{$3}, $4 );
    }

         $trade_id cmp $btrade_id
      || $month <=> $bmonth
      || $date <=> $bdate
      || $row_num <=> $brow_num;

}
```

and i rwrite this script to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#use Smart::Comments;

use constant RegExp_parse_name => qr/(\w+)_(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})_(\d+)/;

#qr/([A-Z0-9]+_\d+_[A-Z0-9]+)_(\d+)-([A-Z][a-z]{2})-(20\d{2})_(\d+)[.]xml/;

#create month hash
my @month = qw/Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec/;
my %months;
foreach my $index ( 0 .. $#month ) { $months{ $month[$index] } = $index }

#generate tmp array for special sort
my @tmp_scons;
while ( my $str = <DATA> ) {
    chomp($str);
    my ( $trade_id, $date, $month, $year, $row_num ) =
      $str =~ RegExp_parse_name;
    $trade_id or next;
    $month = $months{$month};
    push @tmp_scons, [ "$trade_id:$year-$month-$date:$row_num", $str ];
}
my @scons = map $_->[1], sort { $a cmp $b } @tmp_scons;

### @tmp_scons:@tmp_scons
### @scons:@scons
### %months:%months
my %is;

foreach my $str (@scons) {
    my ( $trade_id, $date, $month, $year, $row_num ) =
      $str =~ RegExp_parse_name;
    if ( !$is{$trade_id} ) {
        print "$str\n";
    }
    $is{$trade_id}++;

    #print "$str\n";
}

__DATA__
N1089767N_7_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78919186.xml
N1089767N_7_SWOPT_25-Jun-2011_72745892.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78979055.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_20-Jul-2011_69380887.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_29-Jun-2011_74754662.xml
```

but it doesn't sort correctly what the matter?

Answer (score 13):

In this line:

```
my @scons = map $_->[1], sort { $a cmp $b } @tmp_scons;
```

You are sorting the transformed data, and then pulling out the origional.  However, in your sort block, when you write `$a cmp $b` you are comparing the array references, so perl is doing something like `'ARRAY(0x123412)' cmp 'ARRAY(0x234234)'` rather than looking at your transformed data, which is in the first element of that array.

Rewrite the line as follows:

```
my @scons = map $_->[1], sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @tmp_scons;
```

And you will be correctly sorting on the transformed value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#as a result
#!/usr/bin/env perl
######################################
#      $URL: http://mishin.narod.ru $
#     $Date: 2011-09-14 19:53:20 +0300 (Web, 14 Sep 2011) $
#   $Author: mishin nikolay $
# $Revision: 1.02 $
#   $Source: get_latest.pl $
#   $Description: Sort trades and get latest $
##############################################################################
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);

our $VERSION = '0.01';

my $RGX_SHORT_MESS = qr/^(\w+)_(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})_(\d+)/smo;
my $RGX_LONG_MESS  = qr/^message[.](\w+)[.](\w+)_(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})/smo;

#create month hash
my %months;

# two symbol for correct literal matching
@months{qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )} =
  ( '00' .. '11' );

my ( $result, $index );

my $file = shift;    #'file_names.txt';
open my $fh, q{<}, $file or croak "unable to open:$file $ERRNO";
process_data($fh);    #my @file_names = <$fh>;
close $fh or croak "unable to close: $file $ERRNO";

sub process_data {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    while ( my $str = <$fh> ) {

        chomp $str;
        my $search_str = $str;
        my $trade_id;

        if ( $search_str =~ s/$RGX_SHORT_MESS/$4-$months{$3}-$2:$5/sm ) {
            $trade_id = $1;
        }
        elsif ( $search_str =~ s/$RGX_LONG_MESS/$5-$months{$4}-$3:$1/sm ) {
            $trade_id = $2;
        }
        else { next }

        # so, from now we are search BIGGEST value & ignore less
        next
          if ( exists $index->{$trade_id}
            && ( $index->{$trade_id} gt $search_str ) );

        $index->{$trade_id}  = $search_str;
        $result->{$trade_id} = $str;

    }

    # $result

    foreach ( reverse sort keys %{$result} ) {
        print $result->{$_} . "\n";
    }
    return;
}
__DATA__
N1089767N_7_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78919186.xml
N1089767N_7_SWOPT_25-Jun-2011_72745892.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_03-Jul-2011_78979055.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_20-Jul-2011_69380887.xml
N1089772L_9_SWOPT_29-Jun-2011_74754662.xml
message.110530033311A4259348AS26.A4259348AS_26_SWOPT_01-Jul-2011.xml
message.110530033311A4259348AS26.A4259348AS_26_SWOPT_31-May-2011.xml
A4259348AS_26_SWOPT_29-Jun-2011_74754662.xml
```